# Non-Profit looking to switch out of the A2P 10DLC requirements

Tags: twilio

I have received countless emails from Twilio stating that I had steps to take to avoid being blocked under A2P 10DLC requirements. Initially I completed the steps required, or so I believed, which stopped the emails for a bit. But they are back. I have reached out to Support many, many, many times and have a few ticket numbers at this point. BUT Support has otherwise been less than useless. After the ticket is generated there is no communication, even after sending update requests with those ticket numbers referenced. The thing is we do NOT send campaign messages, so all I want to do is switch us out of the non-profit account status to s regular for profit account - which I have stated to support many times also. I have even reached out to sales a few times. I can't believe how unresponsive they have all been. Absolutely the worst customer service I have ever experienced.

Any suggestions on how to change the account status myself, since I cannot count on support to do anything, would be greatly appreciated. Or if you have likewise found Twilio to be horrible and switched to another service (keeping the same #) that information would also be appreciated.

I have easily sent 25 emails to Twilio support requesting assistance switching from non-profit account status to a regular account status because we do not use campaigns and don't fall under A2P 10DLC.

Comment: I don't think what you are seeking to do will stop the A2P 10DLC warning emails. Couldn't you just ignore them? If you don't send text messages then you won't mind if they are being blocked.

Comment: Thank you Jassent. We use the service regularly, but only about 30-50 messages per month. And it's not that I want to stop getting the messages, it's more about aligning our account with usage and requirements. And eliminating the recurring threat of messages being blocked.

Comment: If you are sending messages you will need to do the A2P 10DLC. If you want to try to "switch" to the sole proprietor, then just create a new 10DLC brand/campaign and choose Sole Proprietor but read the requirements because it doesn't sound like you meet them: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/9550596959643-A2P-10DLC-Sole-Proprietor-Brands-FAQ